# current time date format with milliseconds by using XSLT Version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML:

```
<root>
<Name>Test</Name>
<DOB>10-11-1989</DOB>
<root>
```

I need to get current time date format with milliseconds by using XSLT.
I am using **XSLT version-1.0.**.

After Trasformation my XML should look like below:

```
<root>
<Name>Test</Name>
<DOB>10-11-1989</DOB>
<currentDate>2014-05-21-01.25.32.000000</currentDate>
<root>
```

I found solutions for version-2.0 but, that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, using Java, that works with Xalan and is default available in the ORACLE JRE.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="java">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
            <dateTimeStamp>
                <xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS a'), java:java.util.Date.new())" />
            </dateTimeStamp>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From http://www.heber.it/?p=1053.

If you want to have 12-hr format, simply change

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'), java:java.util.Date.new())" />
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a'), java:java.util.Date.new())" />
```

it outputs:

```
<root>
    <Test>tested</Test>
    <dateTimeStamp>2014-05-23-01.57.04.000441 PM</dateTimeStamp>
</root>
```

Comment: Joel,When I use ur solution I am not getting time stamp value.
<root>
   <Name>Test</Name>
   <DOB>10-11-1989</DOB>
   <dateTimeStamp />
</root>

Comment: Thanks Joel. It works.But it is displaying 24 hr format.
<dateTimeStamp>2014-05-21-17.15.01.000605</dateTimeStamp>
How to get 12 hr format ? 
I will add +1 to this question

Comment: @user3659654 Your (rather unorthodox) timestamp format does not seem to have room for AM/PM indication. If using a 12-hour time format, how will you distinguish between noon and midnight, for example? I will add +1 to your question if you explain that.

Comment: I have edited my answer. it now shows a 12-hr format timestamp.

Comment: Joel, It is displaying AM or PM but not in 12-hour Format

Comment: sorry, my bad `HH` there should be `hh`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Joel for your support.
@michael.hor257k You are right. But its not me who see time and distinguish between noon and midnight.
My requirement in my project asks 12-hr format.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 alone does not provide any means to get the current date or time.

If your processor supports it, you can use the date-time() EXSLT extension function - however, I don't think this will include milliseconds.

Alternatively, you could pass the timestamp as a parameter to the stylesheet during runtime.